# Proof involving product of families of classes

Tags: functions

Problem statement, as written:

In the next three exercises (exercises 4, 5, and 6), assume the following:
$\cup_{i\in I}A_i = \cup_{j\in J}B_j = X$.

6. Let $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ and $\{B_j\}_{j\in J}$ be families of classes. Prove the following:

a) $(\Pi_{i\in I}A_i) \cap (\Pi_{j\in J}B_j) = \Pi_{(i,j)\in I\times J}(A_i \cap B_j)$.

Proof: $(\rightarrow)$ Let $f\in (\Pi_{i\in I}A_i) \cap (\Pi_{j\in J}B_j)$. Then $f\colon I \rightarrow X$,  where $f(i)\in A_i$ for every $i\in I$; analogously, $f\colon J \rightarrow X$,  where $f(j)\in B_j$ for every $j\in J$. To see that $f\in \Pi_{(i,j)\in I\times J}(A_i \cap B_j)$, we must show that 1) $dom(f) = I\times J$, 2) $ran(f)\subseteq \cup_{(i,j)\in I\times J} (A_i \cap B_j)$, 3) if $f(x) = y_1$ and $f(x) = y_2$, then $y_1=y_2$, and 4) $\forall(i,j)\in I\times J, f((i,j))\in A_i \cap B_j$. To prove 1)....

I'm a little hesitant on how to proceed here; there's no indication that $I$ and $J$ are meant to be the same index set (other problems explicitly state this, if intended), but it seems it must follow that $I=J$, since $dom(f)=I$ and $dom(f)=J$, by hypothesis. But even if so, how can I show that any $x\in dom(f)$ turns out to be an ordered pair (i.e., $x\in I\times J$)? Any pointers?

Comment: This all seems ridiculous -- $I = J = I \times J$? I think $\Pi$ is meant to be $\bigcap$: then a) would not only make sense, it would be true.

Comment: Yeah, this book seems to have a lot of issues with the exercises. Maybe I should find a separate resource for better and more accurate problems.

Comment: What's the book? Perhaps we can suggest something comparable and better-proofread, or just better.

Comment: Charles Pinter- A Book of Set Theory. Jech's book, suggested elsewhere, seems at a high level- I think I could pick it up- but it would involve filling in a lot of steps and struggling to make sure I actually understand what I might think I understand. Jech and Hrbacek have a nice book it seems so far. going back and forth between those two for now. Any new suggestions are welcomed!

Comment: I don't know Pinter's book, and while the range of topics seems good, the state of the exercises may be dismal. Hrbacek and Jech is in its 3rd edition, written by world class guys who have polished it. Jech's book isn't the place to build facility with sets & operations on them - it really assumes that.